# Ajax call to MVC controllers

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass some data with ajax call to a c# mvc controller. Even though the task should be straight forward, I am unable to get the mvc controller to read the data I'm passing through the ajax call....

I've implemented the following code within my MVC controller

```
[HttpPost]
public string tt(string o)
{            
    return o;
}

[HttpPost]
public string tt2(string o)
{
    return "lala";
}
```

And I'm triggering the following ajax calls from the browser

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/tt2",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;",
    data: JSON.stringify({ o: 'asdas'}),     
    success: function(e){console.log(e+'    correct');},
    error: function(e){console.log(e+'    incorrect');}
});

$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/tt",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;",
    data: JSON.stringify({ o: 'asdas'}),     
    success: function(e){console.log(e+'    correct');},
    error: function(e){console.log(e+'    incorrect');}
});
```

As a result when running the first ajax call the result is

```
lala    correct
```

And for the second ajax call, the result is

```
undefined    correct
```

In the mean time these are some stuff I tried

- Adding `dataType: "json",` to the ajax call
- Changing the string data from `{o: 'asdas'}` to `'asdas'`
- Removing the `JSON.stringify`
- Adding the `charset=utf-8` to the contentType
- Changing the ajax call type and MVC controller method from `POST` to `GET` to `PUT`
- Changing the MVC controller method parameter from `string` to `int`
- Removing the `error` method from the ajax call
- Changing the data from `data: {o: 'asdas'}` to `data: {"o":"asdas"}`
- Changing the data from `data: {"o":"asdas"}` to `data: JSON.stringify({"o":"asdas"})`

I know that simple string or int can be passed through the URL as query strings but it would be an issue when passing a list of objects..

Something aside is that the call is being done correctly to the URL because when I set a breakpoint within the called method, it does get triggered but the parameter always is null..

Any thoughts on how to make ajax call work?

Comment: Take a moment a look at this [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a4cqYM).

Comment: I copied your example, didn't modify any single thing. It works perfectly. Maybe the FromBody fixes it if it didn't perfectly bind from the View.

Comment: I'm thinking what @WillyDavidJr said is correct as your example builds and works fine for me.

Comment: Then I guess it would be the framework I'm using? I'm using .Net Core 2.0. 
With the FromBody works, but without it, it doesn't work. I'll change around the property of the method and change it to the object I need to work with. Thanks a lot for the quick response.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, creating a form does work as well, but I would prefer creating the data model from jquery without having to have the form elements in place. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @sgrech then you didn't look at the example... the ajax data looks like `{Answer: '', Question: $('#Question').val()}` which is not a form, but a javascript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
[HttpPost]
public string tt([FromBody]string o)
{            
    return o;
}
```

Comment: Unless you've derived from an ApiController, this is not necessary as the ModelBinder already picks up [Values from the body via the JsonValueProviderFactory](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ValueProviderFactories.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Your request should be like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("tt", "Home")',
            data: {
                "o": "asdasdas"
            },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (response) {

            },
            error: function (xhr) {
            }
            });
```

Comment: $.ajax({
     url: "http://localhost:59807/Home/tt",
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
     dataType: "json",
     data:{
                "o": "asdas"
            },
     success: function(e){console.log(e+'    correct');},
  error: function(e){console.log(e+'    incorrect');}
  });

Still doesn't work.